# = not defined for std::search when using const string&

Tags: c++, search

I have the following code, **which works fine**, however when I change the `iter getB(string& s , string& tag);` function definition to `iter getB(const string& s , const string& tag);` I get the error pasted at the end. I believe the `=` operator is not defined because with this new function definition, if I don't assign the result of `search` to `i` the program compiles, though later resulting in a segmentation fault, which I believe is expected. Can someone explain to me why I can't assign the result of `search` when the function definition contains `const` keywords. Thank you.

**the code:**

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;
typedef string::iterator iter;
iter getB(string& s , string& tag);
int main (){
   string line = "hello, how are you?";
   string tag = "how";
   iter i = getB(line,tag);

   for(i ; i!=line.end(); i++){
       cout << *i ;
   }

   cout << endl;
return 0;
}
iter getB(string& s , string& tag)
{
    iter i;

    i = search(s.begin() , s.end() , tag.begin() , tag.end());

    return i;
}
```

~
~
**the error message with the altered function definition:**

`test1.cpp: In function ‘iter getB(const std::string&, const std::string&)’:
test1.cpp:24: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘i = std::search [with _ForwardIterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _ForwardIterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >](((const std::string*)s)->std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::begin [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>](), ((const std::string*)s)->std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::end [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>](), ((const std::string*)tag)->std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::begin [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>](), ((const std::string*)tag)->std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::end [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]())’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:637: note: candidates are: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >& __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::operator=(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&)`

Comment: Works for me. What compiler are you using?

Comment: VC++ 2010 also compiles without any errors.

Comment: The question says that the posted code compiles, but doesn't if the arguments to `getB` are changed to `const string &`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore you using MSVS ?

Comment: I am using i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `s` is a `const string &`, then `s.begin()`, and hence the return type of `search`, is `string::const_iterator`. This is not convertible to `string::iterator`, which is the type of `i`.

This is as it should be, since otherwise that conversion would break `const`-correctness by allowing you to modify the string. You should change the type of `i` to `string::const_iterator`, or perhaps `auto` if you're using C++11.

Answer (score 4):

For a `const string`, `begin()` and `end()` return `std::string::const_iterator` not `std::string::iterator`. You can convert an `iterator` to a `const_iterator`, but not vice versa.

The quick solution would be to change your typedef:

```
typedef string::const_iterator iter;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you pass in a const iterator to std::search, then the return value is also a const iterator (it will be of the same type as the first iterator passed in)

change this:

```
typedef string::iterator iter;
```

to this:

```
typedef string::const_iterator iter;
```